# iOS user css stylesheets for Safari

Tags: ios, safari, accessibility, css

On macOS and other desktop systems you can override the CSS from a website and add yor preferences -- change the header font, line spacing, text colour etc.

Is there away to do this automatically per site on the iPad?

There is a question [Is CSS injection possible on iPad using Safari?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/377492/is-css-injection-possible-on-ipad-using-safariasking) similar but this requires opening the page first then running a shortcut for each page. The desktop addins apply the styles by domain name so no extra user involvement.

Comment: Despite your last paragraph this looks like a duplicate (the original question basically asks the same thing after all)

Comment: Yes but it is not answered as I explained n in the last paragraph

Comment: The key reason probably is that it can't be done, so the only answer is about to accomplish something similar. Setting a bounty for "answers which work in the background" on the original question may yield additional answers if they exist (and you surely have enough rep for this :-))

Comment: More details on possible solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916335/can-i-over-ride-css-with-user-css-on-mobile-safari/#72932863

Answer (score 1):

Automatically?

> **No.**    *(at least not as of mid-2022)*

---

If someone were to write a Safari extension*, *or* if Apple adds support in a future iOS version, then the answer would of course change.

**(if even possible: macOS Safari has the [Cascadea extension](https://cascadea.app/)… if doing the same thing on iOS/iPadOS were trivial, it seems that extension’s developer might have already done so)*

---

*For more background details and possible workarounds, please see the answers at: “[Can I over-ride CSS with user-css on Mobile Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916335/can-i-over-ride-css-with-user-css-on-mobile-safari/#72932863)”*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see the [Hyperweb extension](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/hyperweb/id1581824571), which allows the injection of a custom CSS on any website to change its style as a free feature, and its instructions on [How to inject custom CSS in iOS Safari](https://guide.hyperweb.app/styling/custom-css/).