# Why does this I in a black rectangle with a line through appear on my iPad Pro screen, and how to get rid of it permanently?

Tags: ipad, ipados

This black sign appears on my iPad Pro screen many times, sometimes in one top corner of the screen, sometimes on different other places on the screen, but I guess always on the Safari tabs, as I’ve never seen it on the screen when using other apps! The size is less than one square centimeter.

[image: White I on black rectangle with white line through]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why does it appear on my screen? And how can I get rid of it forever?

Comment: Seriously? No one else has that problem?

Comment: There's not enough context here.  What are you doing at the time you see it?  Where exactly on the screen or Safari tab?  What issue is it causing you?

Comment: It seems odd that in the screenshot iPad is spelled `ipad` - When did you first notice it? From the day you purchased the device or only on a certain website?  As @Allan says, need a bit more context.  Personally, my iPad Pro has never shown this that I have noticed.

Comment: @bjbk as mentioned in the question, the sign is the black rectangle. The ipad was added when i took the screenshot. I don’t know why. But the sign is the black rectangle with an I that has a line through it. I changed the photo. It appears irregularly, and not in particular places. Right now it is a bit above this comment. And then, now, it goes below this comment and again above. While I am typing this comment, it has changed its place several times. I don’t know why? And I don’t remember when I saw it the first time.

Comment: Assuming you have a semi-recent backup, I would do a factory reset and see if it persists.

Comment: There's even less context now.  I was hoping to see it's location on the screen in relation to other things.  If your content is sensitive, **redact that,** not enlarge the symbol and remove any possibility of understanding it's context.  You also didn't answer any of the questions I asked like what were you doing, what app were you running.  We can't reproduce the conditions if we don't know what they are.

Comment: @Allan Like I said in the response to another comment, it is not regular when it shows up. As mentioned there, I was writing my comment here and it showed a couple of times. But this time I haven’t see it while writing this comment.

Comment: @Allan More pictures added.

Comment: What are you using when you write? E.g. Apple Pencil, external keyboard, on-screen keyboard, voice e.t.c.

Comment: @iTunes iPad keyboard folio.

Comment: Does the mysterious icon appear if you use another input mechanism (e.g. on-screen keyboard)?

Comment: @iTunes External keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is happening in Safari several additions could inject content that doesn’t directly come from the websites you listed:

1. VPN or network injection (very unlikely as it would break most secure sites that use TLs)
2. Content blockers (very suspect, try disabling them all, then enabling then half at a time)
3. [CSS modifications](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/378087/5472) (less common, but very likely if you use them)
4. Developer tools and experimental features (Settings app > Safari > Advanced)

The developer tools and attaching your iPad to desktop safari and opening web inspector is the tool I use to dissect an odd website behavior. I can not reproduce your issue despite trying, but if someone can show how to reproduce it, I would love to help solve it.